# How to open the menu to start the application with swrevealviewcontroller?

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using the swrevealviewcontroller library, and I would like when my app starting the hamburger menu is open. I 've been looking at the library , but I did not see how it could do.

Thanks

Comment: You can open it in the viewDidLoad? or that's not what you want

Comment: did you tried trigger your button ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code in your viewdidload method.

```
 UIApplication.sharedApplication()
        .sendAction(barBtn.action, to: barBtn.target,
            from: self, forEvent: nil)
```

We are trigger (or) fire the button click programatically,so that your menu will open .

This will do what ever you want :)

Comment: I have a problem if I put this. Maybe I am wrong. I use a UIBarButtonItem

Comment: @jorgemht wait a minute

Comment: @jorgemht now try this you will get :)